# jQuery Find all href but not in

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML document

I want all the href, but not the href inside "main"

Only "main" may be used for this in the jQuery

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a href="url1">link text 1</a>
</header>

<main>
  <a href="url2">link text 2</a>
</main>

<footer>
  <a href="url3">link text 3</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) like:

```
$('a').not('main > a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

**Example**

```js
$('a').not('main > a').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a href="url1">link text 1</a>
</header>

<main>
  <a href="url2">link text 2</a>
</main>

<footer>
  <a href="url3">link text 3</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with jQuery, you can use jQuery's built-in [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) function.

```js
$('a').not('main > a').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a href="url1">link text 1</a>
</header>
<main>
  <a href="url2">link text 2</a>
</main>
<footer>
  <a href="url3">link text 3</a>
</footer>
```

If you want a pure HTML5 solution, you can use the native CSS 3/4 [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('body *:not(main) > a').forEach(el =>
  console.log(el.getAttribute('href')));
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="url1">link text 1</a>
</header>
<main>
  <a href="url2">link text 2</a>
</main>
<footer>
  <a href="url3">link text 3</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Beware though the non-jquery version would only work for this particular case where the <a> is always a direct child of the main. If there was an other parent in between, `body *:not(main)  a` would not work, while jQuery's `$("a").not("main  a")` would. (btw, why the `body` in here?)